# Can F1 OPT +H1B claim tax treaty benefits

Tags: united-states, income-tax, india, irs, non-resident

I have been in USA for about two and a half half years on F1 visa. In 2013 I was on at F1 and F1 OPT till 30 September 2013. After that I switch to H1B status. I am a nonresident alien for tax purposes. I am an Indian citizen. Am I eligible to claim US India tax treaty the benefits per Chapter 5 Pub 519 for 1040 NR (http://www.irs.gov/publications/p519/ch05.html)? The treaty would give me a **standard** deduction of $6100. I am not sure because its sites like sprintax on Glacier Tax Prep I not taking this into account then I am computing taxes using them. Is there a limit on the number of years for which I can claim treaty benefits?

Answer (score 2):

There is a limit on how many years you can claim treaty benefits, and when you're on H1b - you're resident for tax purposes (except for the first year where you can usually *choose* not to be).

If you're a non-resident - you can always itemize, I do not know how "the treaty would give you an itemized deduction of $6100". What the **Indo-US** treaty may be able to give you in some cases is a *standard* (i.e.: not itemized) deduction, which is generally unavailable for non-residents.

---

Since you're specifically asking about the *STANDARD* deduction available to Indian **students** under the Indo-US treaty, then the answer for this specific question is **NO**. If for any part of the year you're in any status other than the one allowing the deduction under the treaty (i.e.: any status that is not F1/J1) - you **cannot** claim the *standard* deduction.

If you're a H1b filing as non-resident - you can *only* claim *itemized* deduction.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Here is a link to 1040 NR EZ http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f1040nre.pdf
Per Page 8 of instructions http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/i1040nre.pdf, Residents of India can claim standard deduction instead of Itemized Deduction. But as you can see in 1040NR EZ form there is no section for itemized deductions. (instructions for Line 11). Under what section should the $6100 go?

Comment: It is confusing in the 1040 NR EZ form that Line 6 though reserved for tax treaties is not used anywhere else in the form. Based on this http://international.uoregon.edu/isss/taxes/info/SPT/NonResident/1040NREZ, we can fill $6100 in Line 11 but still seems odd that line 6 is not used anywhere.

Comment: Actually Line 6 does seem to be used in special cases, see Page 8 Itemized Deductions Worksheet http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/i1040nre.pdf. But it seems there is an exception for Indian students.

Comment: 1040NR EZ is a subset of 1040NR. Instructions for filling 1040NR EZ are also a subset of instructions for filling 1040NR. 1040NR is used if you want to report more types of income.

Comment: @RohitBanga ... if it doesn't support what you need - you fill the full form.

Comment: Filling the full form will not solve the problem as I will have to specify the deduction in Itemized Deduction in the full form also. Also I just heard back from Glacier. They do not support treaty deductions when a student switches status to H1B. So that explains why the treaty deduction is not computed automatically.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Glacier is for students only, people with salaries can afford a tax preparer.

Comment: I was confused why Glacier Tax Prep and Sprintax computations are not matching manual computations I did based on instructions sheet. Since they were not matching I was doubtful of my calculations. Since the software does not support my usecase, I guess that explains it.

Comment: @Rohit, I'm not sure I understand your problem, but I'm guessing it is because you're trying to put *standard* deduction on your form. You cannot put a standard deduction on your form. H1b filing as non-resident can **only** use itemized deduction.

Comment: Right can only use itemized deduction but "standard deduction" has to be reported in the Itemized Deduction section for Indian students. As also mentioned here: http://international.uoregon.edu/isss/taxes/info/SPT/NonResident/1040NREZ. See instructions for Line 11.

Comment: @Rohit but you're not a student. You said you're on h1b - you cannot use standard deduction. The Indo-US treaty only allows standard deduction for students and apprentices (i.e.: you're in F1/J1 status). Since part of the year you're in H1b status - standard deduction is not available for you.

Comment: But part of the year I was on student status.  Do you have any references that define whether I can consider myself a student or not?

Comment: @Rohit you cannot get a standard deduction for partial year, even if you're considered a resident. You're not student for the whole year since you're on H1b now. You cannot claim standard deduction for this year.

Comment: "except for the first year where you can usually choose not to be" That seems backwards. He is a nonresident alien for 2013, because he does not meet the Substantial Presence Test for 2013. He can *choose* to be dual-status for 2013 through a painstaking process where he would have to file extension, etc. If he is not married, he *cannot* "choose" to be resident alien for 2013 even if he wanted to.

Comment: @user102008 I was talking about the period of time on H1b... Painstaking or not (not, actually) - its an option.